# Right npm package to use ADAL with Angular 6

Tags: angular, azure, adal

I am a little confused about the right usage of ADAL with Angular 6. On one hand there is adal-angular4, what can be found here:

https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4

This package supports Angular 6 as well, even though the name still contains the 4. 
And then there is also adal-angular6, what seems to be the same,  but does contain AdalHTTPService-Object. 
In adal-angular4-package I have to use the HTTP interceptor.

I am confused which package to use.
Or does it just not matter?

Answer (score 4):

The package adal-angular4 will work just fine with Angular6. As an alternative you can look at - https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Thats a pretty new npm package. Why are there three different packages, that all do the same? Do they all use the original adal angular?

Comment: Yes basically they are all wrappers on top of adal.js - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js that can be imported directly in your module

Comment: This is the best package in my opinion, the set up is much cleaner than benaran's
https://github.com/manishrasrani/ms-adal-angular6

I appreciate both dev's work though, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

The package https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4 worked like a charm for Angular 6.

And the title already says that it supports all 4, 5 and 6 now